# pytorch : unable to understand model.forward function

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am learning deep learning and am trying to understand the pytorch code given below. I'm struggling to understand how the probability calculation works. Can somehow break it down in lay-man terms. Thanks a ton.

> ps = model.forward(images[0,:])

```
# Hyperparameters for our network
input_size = 784
hidden_sizes = [128, 64]
output_size = 10

# Build a feed-forward network
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_sizes[0]),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[0], hidden_sizes[1]),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[1], output_size),
                      nn.Softmax(dim=1))
print(model)

# Forward pass through the network and display output
images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))
images.resize_(images.shape[0], 1, 784)
print(images.shape)
ps = model.forward(images[0,:])
```

Comment: We usually answer questions in non-layman's terms here ;-)  You might get an answer quicker on Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm a layman so I'll help you with the layman's terms :)

```
input_size = 784
hidden_sizes = [128, 64]
output_size = 10
```

These are parameters for the layers in your network. Each neural network consists of `layers`, and each `layer` has an input and an output shape.

Specifically `input_size` deals with the input shape of the first layer. This is the `input_size` of the entire network. Each sample that is input into the network will be a 1 dimension vector that  is length 784 (array that is 784 long).

`hidden_size` deals with the shapes inside the network. We will cover this a little later.

`output_size` deals with the output shape of the last layer. This means that our network will output a 1 dimensional vector that is length 10 for each sample.

Now to break up model definition line by line:

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_sizes[0]),
```

The `nn.Sequential` part simply defines a network, each argument that is input defines a new layer in that network in that order.

`nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_sizes[0])` is an example of such a layer. It is the first layer of our network takes in an input of size `input_size`, and outputs a vector of size `hidden_sizes[0]`. The size of the output is considered "hidden" in that it is not the input or the output of the whole network. It "hidden" because it's located inside of the network far from the input and output ends of the network that you interact with when you actually use it.

This is called `Linear` because it applies a linear transformation by multiplying the input by its weights matrix and adding its bias matrix to the result. (Y = Ax + b, Y = output, x = input, A = weights, b = bias).

```
nn.ReLU(),
```

ReLU is an example of an activation function. What this function does is apply some sort of transformation to the output of the last layer (the layer discussed above), and outputs the result of that transformation. In this case the function being used is the `ReLU` function, which is defined as `ReLU(x) = max(x, 0)`. Activation functions are used in neural networks because they create non-linearities. This allows your model to model non-linear relationships.

```
nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[0], hidden_sizes[1]),
```

From what we discussed above, this is a another example of a `layer`. It takes an input of `hidden_sizes[0]` (same shape as the output of the last layer) and outputs a 1D vector of length `hidden_sizes[1]`.

```
nn.ReLU(),
```

Apples the `ReLU` function again.

```
nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[1], output_size)
```

Same as the above two layers, but our output shape is the `output_size` this time.

```
nn.Softmax(dim=1))
```

Another activation function. This activation function turns the logits outputted by `nn.Linear` into an actual probability distribution. This lets the model output the probability for each class. At this point our model is built.

```
# Forward pass through the network and display output
images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))
images.resize_(images.shape[0], 1, 784)
print(images.shape)
```

These are simply just preprocessing training data and putting it into the correct format

```
ps = model.forward(images[0,:])
```

This passes the images through the model (forward pass) and applies the operations previously discussed in layer. You get the resultant output.

Comment: truly a laymen. Very well explained!